# Convert asp.net class into the dll

Tags: asp.net, class, dll, controls

I my asp.net application, I have created a class which is inheting the textbox class with custom feature. Can I wrap up this class in a dll, so that I can use it in my future projets? How can I do that?

Comment: Where have you created your class?

Comment: @Dan Puzey  In app_code folder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Start a new Class Library project.
2. Move the class to the Class Library project.
3. Build the Class Library Project.
4. Include a reference to the resulting DLL from the Web Application Project.